# Properties do not exist for data type

Tags: node.js, typescript, discord, discord.js

I am new to TypeScript and I am having two problems with data types.

This is my code:

```
const say: object = {
  name: "say",
  aliases: [""],
  description: "",
  usage: "",
  run: (client: object, msg: object, args: string) => {
    if (!args[0]) return;
    msg.channel.send(args.join(" "));
  },
};

export default say;
```

The errors that come out are:

> Property 'channel' does not exist on type 'object'.

> Property 'join' does not exist on type 'string'.

I did a `console.log (typeof msg)` and `console.log (typeof args)` and indeed its data type is `object` and `string`.

I'm looking for an alternative to change the data type to `any`.

Comment: Try looking for how to declare your own types in **Type**Script. Having a better understanding of plain JavaScript will help too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are sure about the type of msg, then you can create your own type.

```
interface Msg {
    channel: type here;
}
at the run, use this interface. (client: object, msg: Msg, args: string)
```

if you are not sure about its structure, then just say 'msg' there without any typedef.

do you mean `args: string[]`. It doesn't make sense to apply a join on a string here.

Comment: I didn't know that `string []` is also a data type. Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

I assume that `channel` and `message` are `discord.js` types. So you can check discord.js types from here : https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/tree/master/typings

and you can use Message type like this:

```js
import {Message }from "discord.js"
```

in the second question. join is not a property for string. it's the property for arrays so probably args would be `string[]`

Comment: I didn't know that `string []` is also a data type. Thanks!!